# Simple AD FS 3.0 external access

Tags: adfs

I'm setting up the ability for users to log in remotely to access web resources via AD FS 2.0 and Web Application Proxy. What I'm seeing right now is that when I attempt to log in remotely I initially get the AD FS login form, and then once I enter in valid credentials I'm immediately prompted with a 401 login. If I enter *that* correctly I can browse the published application. What do I need to look at between the Proxy and/or ADFS server(s) to correct this so I'm not entering credentials twice? I figure this should be a relatively common use-case but finding the correct documentation is proving difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was closer than I thought. I needed to add a Non-Claims-Aware Relying Party with an arbitrary URL. Once I did that everything worked exactly as expected.